# Gradle 7.6 Advanced Algorithms

Tags: gradle

I know this not a common question that would normally be asked in the support forum. We use the open source version of Gradle in our CI/CD pipeline to build our backend applications and am in the process of getting Gradle 7.6 approved to use in our environment. I am being asked by our Risk Management group whether any advanced algorithms, predictive analytics, dynamic components, machine learning, or artificial intelligence are used within or by this product, and whether any part of the input or output process involves any of these techniques.

I found [this article](https://gradle.com/gradle-enterprise-solutions/predictive-test-selection/?_ga=2.108914882.1328785967.1675275114-118460021.1672942896) and the enterprise edition, but does it apply to the open sourced version as well. I understand that the Gradle build tool and the Gradle Enterprise software are complete separate products but couldn't get a straight answer on the Gradle support forum which I could understand. I didnt know about this forum so here I am with the same question. Can someone please provide some clarity and shed some light?

Comment: That's a lot of terms that aren't precisely defined, which might be why you are struggling to get a straight answer. What exactly, for instance, is an "advanced algorithm"? Gradle has some nice features, but it's not pushing the boundaries of computing theory. All in all, I think you'll find Gradle isn't doing anything your risk department will be concerned about: it's "just" a tool for managing a series of tasks.